# Is there a way to transfer my .gradle and .android folder from User Folder to another drive?

Tags: android-studio

I am currently using android studios and I want to transfer the folder of .gradle and .android to another drive.

Answer (score 0):

For .gradle this is pretty easy, you just have to set the environment variable GRADLE_USER_HOME to the path where you want gradle to write the config and caches.

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties